# Batch Job exit status using Spring Cloud Task

Tags: spring-batch, spring-cloud-task

I'm trying to setup a spring batch project to be deployed on Spring Cloud Data Flow server, but first I must "wrapp" it on a Spring Cloud Task application. 
Spring Batch generates metadata (start/end, status, parameters, etc) on `BATCH_` tables. Cloud Task do the same but on `TASK_` tables.

Reading the [documentation of Spring Cloud Task](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-task/docs/2.0.0.M3/reference/htmlsingle/#batch-failures-and-tasks), it said that in order to pass the batch information to the task, it must be set 
`spring.cloud.task.batch.failOnJobFailure=true` and also

> To have your task return the exit code based on the result of the
>   batch job execution, you will need to write your own
>   CommandLineRunner.

So, any indications on how I should write my own `CommandLineRunner` ?

For now, only having set the propertie, if I force the task to fail, I'm getting `Failed to execute CommandLineRunner .... Job UsersJob failed during execution for jobId 3 with jobExecutionId of 6`

Comment: That blurb is _only_ if you want to map custom exit codes based on exit status.  Otherwise, a failed batch job will return a 1 for the exit code.

Comment: @MichaelMinella Then the CommandLineRunner error is expected? Ok. Ty

Comment: @MichaelMinella I notice that the error message logged on data base, is the entire stack trace, actually it's truncated, without showing the real reason of the error (it shows only the part that CommandLineRunner has failed). How I could fix this?

Comment: Enlarge the db field.